# How can I run a program that uses Java 6 or 7?

Tags: windows-7, jre

I'm trying to run [ColorOracle](http://colororacle.org/), a software which simulates color blindness on your monitor. It is written in Java and requires "Java 6 or 7".

I have Java 8 because I foolishly trusted Oracle and updated as they suggested. I am now unable to run the program; it claims that "the registry points to a non-existent Java Runtime".

Oracle no longer provides downloads for Java 7 or earlier, and it is difficult to go through search results and figure out which 3rd party sites are trustworthy.

Is there any way I can run this program?

Comment: "the registry points to a non-existent Java Runtime". First thing to try: Find the program's registry entries and correct it to point to the Java 8 runtime location.  Also, Oracle still offers Java 6 and 7 RE (etc.) [in their archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html).

Comment: To add to @ Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 comment: you can install *multiple* versions of Java JRE. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271609/multiple-java-versions-running-concurrently-under-windows

Comment: Of course doing so leaves you vulnerable to exploits by the Java browser plugin sonnets to disable it if you have older versions of Java installed